# Compiling and linking all dependencies to LLVM bitcode

Tags: c, compilation, clang, llvm

I have a simple C program which is pretty much a hello world program which uses two external functions: printf and strcpy. The program has the following dependencies:

```
ldd app
   linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff36cc4000)
   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4b81932000)
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4b81d2a000)
```

I want to compile the program and all dependencies to LLVM bitcode. If I compile via `clang -c -emit-llvm app.c` it does not compile the dependencies and if I compile without `-c` I get the following error: `-emit-llvm cannot be used when linking`

How can I compile all dependencies to bitcode and link everything together such that there is no more external dependencies?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think this is how things work - you can compile C to LLVM bitcode, but you can't compile x86 code to LLVM, which means what you want to do is impossible. Maybe you could elaborate on why you want to do this?

Comment: I am writing a llvm compiler pass which does static analysis on LLVM IR. To make my analysis more precise I need to analyse the code from extern functions and therefore I need the functions in bitcode.

Comment: well, in that case you should *definitely* compile them from C to LLVM themselves, not try to reverse-compile x86 to LLVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I compile all dependencies to bitcode [..]

Well, you need to **compile** them. That is you need to compile the dependencies (glibc) with clang from their source code (C and assembly) to llvm bitcode. Currently you're linking against already compiled code (which cannot be "uncompiled" / "converted to" LLVM bitcode, at least not in a suitable way).